# DefinitelyTyped d.ts files and Amd Modules with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am importing most of my DefinitelyTyped modules from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped with nuget.

I am wondering if there is something i have missed out because I find all of them missing AMD support.

In most modules i am adding this myself:

```
declare module "toastr" {
    export = Toastr;
}
declare module "knockout.validation" {
    export = KnockoutValidationStatic;
}
declare module "knockoutmapping" {
    export = KnockoutMapping;
}
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
```

When doing this I can do the following:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
import toastr = require('toastr');
```

and it generates my AMD modules correctly.

```
define(["require", "exports", 'toastr'], function(require, exports, __toastr__) {

}
```

I am wondering if there are some other way to do this since I find the amd export defined in the d.ts missing for most libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the definitions do have this section e.g. Underscore. The reason why many of them don't is because the name of the import depends upon how you configure requirejs and the short path name you choose in your configuration.

Comment: Take jquery. I looked at the source and they do configure it under the name jquery. I pushed a update to github and it also got accepted, so  I guess its the correct way of doing it then :) Thanks of answering.

Comment: bonus question: Do i need to define the external modules in the same d.ts file, as you say it depends on my local configuration, so can i just create a myconfiguration.d.ts that has all these local short names?

Comment: the `local configuration` was referring to the paths config for requirejs : http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths e.g. check out http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks

Comment: to answer `myconfiguration.d.ts`, yup go for it. I would actually create a `vendor.d.ts` (always have) which would itself contain references to vendor `.d.ts` files + such configuration + anything I find missing in the configurations for which I will later send a pull request